# How to solve Internal Server Error for my site URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I am trying to redirect **from**:

[www.example.com/name/details.php?url=post-title](http://www.example.com/name/details?url=post-title)

**To:**

[www.example.com/name/blog/post-title](http://www.example.com/name/blog/post-title)

with htaccess rewriting rule. My **.htaccess** code is here:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^custom-([^/]*)$ ./custom/$1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^customadmin-([^/]*)$ ./custom/admin/$1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^domain-([^/]*)$ ./cart.php?a=add&domain=$1 [L,NC]
#RewriteRule ^bd-domain-([^/]*)$ ./cart.php?a=add&domain=register [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^shared-host ?m=dbam&action=shared_hosting [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^reseller-hosting ./?m=dbam&action=reseller_hosting [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress-hosting ./?m=dbam&action=wordpress_hosting [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^dedicated-server ./?m=dbam&action=dedicated_server [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vps-server ./?m=dbam&action=vps_server [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^submit_site ./modules/addons/dbam/action/site_testing/submit_site.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fetch_test_result ./modules/addons/dbam/action/site_testing/fetch_test_result.php [L,NC]
#RewriteRule transfer-domain ./cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer&carttpl=standard&carttpl=standard&systpl=six [L,NC]
RewriteRule transfer-domain ./cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer [L,NC]
RewriteRule contact.php ./index.php [L,NC]


RewriteRule ^/?blog/([0-9]+)$ /details.php?url=$1
```

My blog redirect code is bottom line code.But instead of redirecting it is going to internal server error page. Internal server error information is:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: is `blog` sub folder?

Comment: @Gowri no, it has no blog subfolder, but, there is a folder inside many folder named blog, as you metioned it, i tried with changing url blog to blogs , then the error gone

Comment: there is blog listing page called blog in url ,www.example.com/name/blog

Comment: So same page for blog list and blog details?

Comment: no, there is page called details.php for details page and and blog.php for blog listing showing

Comment: you want url as `/name/blog/post-title`  right?

Comment: yes, that is. for redirecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202197/discussion-between-gowri-and-nayeem-hyder-riddhi).